# Can we use "a lots of"?

Tags: grammar

https://www.workaway.info/467357539488-en.html

Come meet a lots of different nationalities and help us in the aranview country housle in the Doolin area, Ireland

I guess there is a mistake in the above context. I think we cannot use "a lots of". Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct, it's a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is a mistake. The explanation is pretty straightforward: **a** is used for singular nouns, and **lots of** is used for plural ones. Therefore, one can assume the combination of both is wrong.

Comment: While "a lot" should have been used in the OP, you are (at least partially) mistaken to say "lots of is used for plural nouns. " in that "lots of" can be combined with singular, uncountable nouns like "water."